# Cannot get click event fire in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

Here's the piece of my HTML code:

```
<li>
    <a id="section1" href="#" onclick="return false">&raquo; Section 1</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="link1.html" target="showframe" id="tab1" name="tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="link2.html" target="showframe" id="tab2" name="tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

It is actually an jQuery Accordion. Now the line `$('#section1').click();` or `$('#'+section).click();` works, both on IE and Chrome. For inner `Anchor` tags, I tried using:

```
$('a#'+tab_name_from_querystring).click();

$('a[name="'+ tab_name_from_querystring+'"]').click();

$('a#tab1').click();
```

All these don't work in any browser. If I use this:

```
document.getElementById(tab_name_from_querystring).click().
```

It works in IE only, not in Chrome.

Any help please?

**UPDATE:**
Here's the complete JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var params = query.split('&');
    var temp = params[0].split('=');
    var section = temp[1].toLowerCase();
    temp = params[1].split('=');
    var tab = temp[1].toLowerCase();
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#'+section).click();
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("a[name='tab1']").click();  // Did not work
            $('a[name="'+tab+'"]').click(); // Did not work
            document.getElementById(tab).click(); // Works only in IE
        }, 500);

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure `tab_name_from_querystring` is 'tab1' or 'tab2'?

Comment: Yes. As I said, it is working in IE using document.getElementById()

Comment: @Bergi: I do not get any error. If I put an alert() after the .click() statement, I do get an alert.

Comment: Could you please check what content $("a[name='tab1']") has (which length, which elements)? We need to know if the problem comes from matching your element or from firing the event.

Comment: In each browser `query` has the same value?

Comment: @Bergi: The statement `alert($("a[name='tabl1']"))` alerts the link in the HREF attribute of the anchor tag concerned.

Comment: `window.location.href = $( "a#"+tab ).attr( "href" );`
Of course if selector matches that anchor

Comment: @abuduba: Yes. `query` has the same value in each browser. Tested it by alert().

Comment: `$( "a#"+tab ).length` is `1` ?

Comment: @abuduba: OK. Yes. For same url, both IE and Chrome show same values of **section** and **tab** and `$("a[name="+tab+"]").length` as 1.

Comment: What needs to happen when you click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need that:

```
window.location.href = $( "a#tab1" ).attr( "href" );
```

Comment: Tried. No help. I don't understand why document.getElementById() is not working on Chrome. On a normal day, it never is a problem firing event using jQuery and JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked both on IE and Chrome. Did not think of using that technique.

Comment: Now that my problem is solved, does anyone have an idea that how come click event of Anchor tag was is not firing? Logically, it should. And why `document.getElementById(tag).click()` did not work in Chrome?

Comment: This is an invalid syntax. It is always .click()

Comment: Take a look. [https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `a` before `#`

Something like:

```
 $('#'+ tab).click();
```

It works on jsFiddle, view it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ensangalufu/5enBZ/)

Comment: I am surprised to see simple statements like $('#tab1').click() is not working.

Comment: `$("#"+tab).click();` is equal top `document.getElementById(tab).click();`

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$(selector).trigger("click");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have IDs on your links, have you tried:

$('#'+tab_name_from_querystring).click();

or

$('#tab1').click();

Comment: Yes, I tried that. Strangely, it is not firing. Where as on a "normal" day, anything above and this would work.

Comment: Are you actually teling the click event to do something? For example: $('#tab1').click(function() {
  alert('click() called.');
});

Comment: No. As you see in the Anchor tag, the click event should open the page specified in the HREF attribute should be opened in an IFRAME with id **showframe**.

Answer (score 0):

All right. As per the hint by **abuduba**, the following code worked:

```
$('iframe[name="showframe"]').attr('src', $("a[name="+tab+"]").attr('href'));
```

That is, copy the value of the HREF attribute of the Anchor tag to SRC attribute of the desired IFRAME.

Thanks every one